# Excel formula to pick difference between 2 columns but only if difference is less than 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula that picks a difference between 2 columns, but only if the value in column A is equal or maximum less than 1 in column B (either way). My table is as follows:

[image]

I know my logic below is wrong but I tried the below formula and it only picks equal values:

```
=IF(I2=O2,"Yes",IF(I2>=(SUM(O2+1)),"Yes",IF(I2<=(SUM(O2+1)),"Yes")))
```

Can you please advise how to modify the above formula to get the right results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you need to check if column A value is maximum 1 larger or lower than the B column value. And if so, return yes, else return no. Did I understood that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - use `ABS` on the difference and check if `<=1`.

```
=IF(ABS(A2-B2)<=1,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: @SeT, some nice article about the use of this tolerance right [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/value-is-within-tolerance) :)